# Selector this + option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy tratando que cuando se lance el evento Change en un select con la misma clase que otros, se recupere el valor, y si es igual a un dato entonces seleccionar otro del mismo select. Mi problema está en, no se como crear el selector. Lo he intentado así, pero no funciona. Bienvenidas todas las respuestas

```js
$(function(){

  $(document).on('change','.sel',function(){
    var val = parseInt( $(this).val() );
    if( val === 2 ){
      $(this + 'option[value="3"]').prop('selected',true);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="sel">
  <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
  <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
  <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
</select>

<select class="sel">
  <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
  <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
  <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que `this` es un objeto (en particular el select con clase `.sel`) y no puedes simplemente ponerlo en un selector concatenándolo con otro una cadena. La mejor opción que se me ocurre es que uses `.find` para buscar la opción dentro del objeto. Sería un cambio simple:

```
$(this + 'option[value="3"]')
```

por

```
$(this).find('option[value="3"]')
```

Y ya te funcionará:

```js
$(function(){

  $(document).on('change','.sel',function(){
    var val = parseInt( $(this).val() );
    if( val === 2 ){
      $(this).find('option[value="3"]').prop('selected',true);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="sel">
  <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
  <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
  <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
</select>

<select class="sel">
  <option value="1">Valor 1</option>
  <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
  <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Gracias sensei.